# How to compare date inserted from textbox with date from MYSQL db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to compare date inserted in textbox with date from MYSQL database.
My idea is to make car rent form (with FROM date - TO DATE), and after submiting that form, query will check if it is possible to rent that specific car in that period. Anyone had anything similar?
Thanks

Comment: This is pretty broad right now. Where are you having issues, formatting the date, querying, returning results, other?

Comment: What you're asking is too broad and unclear. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We run many queries that are Start and End Date dependent.

```
SELECT * FROM rentCar 
WHERE textBox BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```